# How to render array vertically in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, render

I am creating a quiz app. I want to display result as follows

> Question:
> Your Answer:
> Correct answer:

But currently my code is displaying in a line like this (please see image link to view actual results):-

> Question: Your Answer: Correct Answer:
> Image Link: [https://ibb.co/30v89qS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swv9q.png)

below is my code

```
var indents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

    indents.push(<span><p>Question: {[questionWrongSelection[i], `Your Answer: ${wrongAnswer[i]}`, `Correct Answer:\n ${rightAnswer[i]}`]}</p></span>);
}
```

And this is how the div looks:-

```
<div className='wrongselection'>
                            <hr />
                            <h3>Wrong Answers</h3>
                            <p>
                                <p>
                                    {indents.map(indent=><div>{indent}</div>)}
                                </p>
                            </p>
                        </div>
```

I tried .map method but for some reason it is not working for me or may be I am using it in a wrong way. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add `<br/>` tag ``<br/>Your Answer: ${wrongAnswer[i]}<br/>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enclose the contents on each separate `<p>` tags.

```jsx
var indents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  indents.push(
    <span>
      <p>Question: {questionWrongSelection[i]}</p>
      <p>Your Answer: {wrongAnswer[i]} </p>
      <p>Correct Answer: {rightAnswer[i]}</p>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  indents.push(
    <div className="result">
      <div>
        <strong>Question:</strong> {questionWrongSelection[i]}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Your Answer:</strong> {wrongAnswer[i]}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Correct Answer:</strong> {rightAnswer[i]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

each question, answer, and the correct answer is wrapped inside a  with the class name "result". You can then apply CSS styles to achieve the column layout
css below -

```
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.result div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Make sure to include the CSS styles in your component or in a separate CSS file that is imported into your component. The display: flex; property with flex-direction: column; creates a column layout for the results, and the margin-bottom properties add some spacing between each result.

Finally, render the indents array in your component:

```
return <div>{indents}</div>;
```

Hope this will help!!